# Plivo alphanumeric sender id

Tags: sms-gateway, plivo

I am trying to send SMS to indian numbers using plivo Api. I have set src to alphanumeric id as "ALPHA-NUM".

`parameters.put("src", "ALPHA-NUM");`

But all my sms's are getting received as DM-NOTIFY. How to enable sending sms as alphanumeric sender Ids. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

To send messages with Alphanumeric Sender ID within India, the Sender Id has to be registered with the Carrier. You could get in touch with the Plivo support team (support@plivo.com) to get this done.

Comment: Whether the same Alphanumeric ID will be displayed for all country users and Is there any extra cost for getting these ID.